# Filament: Tab file upload field not enabling

Tags: laravel-filament

I have a function defined to disable the whole tab and only get enabled when certain conditions are met but file upload field is not enabled while other fields are enabled when certain conditions do met. help me what is the reason that trigger this behavior when only one field that is file upload not response to the function:

````php
  Tabs\Tab::make('CAS')
                            ->icon(function (Get $get) {
                                return self::getCas($get('id'));
                            })
                            ->schema([
                                Forms\Components\Group::make()
                                    ->relationship('cas')
                                    ->schema([
                                        Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('request_date')->label('Request Date'),
                                        Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('receive_date')->label('Receive Date'),
                                        SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('cas')
                                            ->collection('cas')
                                            ->openable()
                                            ->downloadable()
                                            ->label('')
                                            ->columnSpan('full')
                                            ->placeholder('Upload CAS Document')
                                            ->acceptedFileTypes(['application/pdf']),

                                    ])->columns(2),
                            ])->disabled(function (Get $get) {
                                $interview = $get('interview');

                                if ((!$interview['schedule_date']  || !$interview['mock_interview_date']
                                    || !$interview['official_interview_date'] || !$interview['result_date'])) {

                                    return true;
                                }
                            }), ```
````